# Print joined string with variable superscript

Tags: string-manipulation

I like to join some strings which I then like to print. A substring contains a number that I like to be printed in scientific format. An example to clearify:

```
aNumber = 2.3*^-17
Print[StringJoin["Value: ", ToString[aNumber]]]
```

The results is:
[image]

How do I get the number to be printed correctly?

Comment: `ToString[aNumber, StandardForm]`.

Comment: ...or use `TraditionalForm` if you want the exponent as a superscript.

Comment: While the question is different, the answer is there.